# How to use momentary joystick switch as toggle switch (Arduino)

Tags: arduino, switch-statement, toggle

i have a motor i can turn CW/CCW with the joystick.
I would like to only be able to do that once i have pressed the joystick button which is a momentary switch.

I believe it should work by making a state change to 1 (or 0) every time the button has been pressed and released and then make the motor only turn when that state is 1.

I've tried different code from google searches but so far, they kind of still make my switch act like a momentary switch. :-S

Can anybody help me how to implement such a function in my code?

```cpp
#include <Wire.h>

// L9110 connections
#define L9110_B_IA 10 // Pin D10 --> Motor B Input A
#define L9110_B_IB 11 // Pin D11 --> Motor B Input B

// Motor Speed & Direction
#define MOTOR_B_PWM L9110_B_IA // Motor PWM Speed
#define MOTOR_B_DIR L9110_B_IB // Motor Direction

const int SW_pin = 2;  //Joystick Switch
const int X_pin = 0; //Joystick X-axis
const int Y_pin = 1; //Joystick Y-axis
const int TresholdHigh = 520; //Deadband for joystick
const int TresholdLow = 480; //Deadband for joystick

void setup()
{
  pinMode(SW_pin, INPUT);
  digitalWrite(SW_pin, HIGH);
  pinMode(13,OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(13,LOW);
  pinMode( MOTOR_B_DIR, OUTPUT );
  pinMode( MOTOR_B_PWM, OUTPUT );
  digitalWrite( MOTOR_B_DIR, LOW ); // Set motor to off
  digitalWrite( MOTOR_B_PWM, LOW );
  Serial.begin(9600);

  Wire.begin();
}

void loop()
{

   if(analogRead(Y_pin) > (TresholdHigh))
    {
      digitalWrite(13,HIGH);
      digitalWrite( MOTOR_B_DIR, LOW );
      analogWrite( MOTOR_B_PWM, 100 );
    }
    else if(analogRead(Y_pin) < (TresholdLow))
    {
      digitalWrite(13,HIGH);
      digitalWrite( MOTOR_B_DIR, HIGH );
      analogWrite( MOTOR_B_PWM, 100 );
    }

    else 
    {
      digitalWrite(13,LOW);
      digitalWrite( MOTOR_B_DIR, LOW );
      digitalWrite( MOTOR_B_PWM, LOW );
    }

}
```

EDIT: I've tried to implement this but it doesn't seem to work. :P

```cpp
const int SW_pin = 2;  //Joystick Switch
boolean buttonState = true; // store for toggle state, false = off true = on

void setup()
{
  pinMode(SW_pin, INPUT);
  digitalWrite(SW_pin, HIGH);
  }


void loop()
 {

  if(SW_pin == LOW && buttonState == false) // if button is pressed and toggled off
{
    buttonState = true; // set button state to on
}

if(SW_pin == LOW && buttonState == true) // if button is pressed and toggled on
{
     buttonState = false; // set button state to off
  }
}
```

Comment: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ButtonStateChange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the link Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams. I used the code in the link and changed the counter-function in the code so it is turning on/off on every second push. Now it works fine. :-)

[Pushbutton state change turtorial](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ButtonStateChange)